# With little electrical knowledge is it possible to get a standard US light socket to power a small 3 W LED?

Tags: led, mains, socket

I was attempting to make an LED light bulb from scratch using a UV 3 W diode and acrylic resin. I wanted it to be able to be used as a regular bulb. Is this possible?

Comment: 120/240V electrical supplies, such as those found in those light sockets, can be dangerous (to both your own personal safety due to electrocution risk, and to your property because of fire risk). If you are unfamiliar with the approaches one would use to make such a device, you should probably not try to do so - consider projects that can operate off safer supplies such as the output of AC->DC adapters, USB, etc.

Comment: The safety aspect is significantly more complex to understand than the technical needs.  If the technical side is a challenge for you then I’d strongly recommend staying well away from mains supply voltages.

Comment: A 3W LED is not especially "small".  Encapsulating it in resin is asking for thermal problems, and the safety considerations attendant upon a very intense point source of UV light are not to be taken lightly either.

Comment: You would want to find some kind of lightbulb construction kit. I've never heard of such a thing existing, but theoretically it could. If I were you, I'd be pretty uncomfortable with playing with mains voltage without sufficient knowledge since it can kill you.

Comment: Maybe make a USB-powered one instead. Then your biggest danger is only that it could overheat and start a fire.

Comment: Of course it is possible, but you need to know what you need to do and how to do it safely. You just can't connect them together without suitable electronics, and what is suitable depends on what are your requirements, i.e. what are the supply requirements of the LED, can you move 3W of heat away from the LED so it does not burn, and if you don't want anyone to get electrocuted if wires are touched, then you need to do the wiring safely or get an isolated  LED driver. Having a 3W UV bulb already does not sound safe at all.

Comment: Since the question specifically asks "with little electrical knowledge" the answer is no.

Comment: Thanks, I figured as much and when I tried to hook the led to a light bulb converter for ceiling lights it more or less exploded but figured it wouldn't hurt to look in to doing it in a non insane way.

Answer (score 3):

The safest way to do this project is to use a commerical power supply to provide a DC voltage to run a custom LED. Then, you could create an AC powered version using a commerical light socket for an LED light bulb if you design your LED to work in the same manner, just be very careful to isolate yourself from the AC lines, do not leave any of them exposed, have access to a breaker panel and attach a fuse to the design, and finally, wear some protective gear such as goggles since explosions from AC power lines can be violent.